# Load Balancer IP Configuration

Tags: linux, azure, ip-address, availability, azure-load-balancer

We have configured load balancer with 2 Linux virtual machines. we have planned to remove one server from the Load balancer and Load balancer too. Is there any possibility to assigning the load balancer ip address to remaining server.

E.g
We have VM1 and VM2 and both configured with load balancer. is there any way to assign load balancer IP to VM1.

Comment: external ip? or internal?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes. Public IP are resources of their own in ARM.

- Confirm the existing Frontend IP address is static
- Assign LB an additional Frontend IP
- Remove existing Frontend IP
- Associate IP with VM1's nic
- Done